# How to do a while loop on an async retrieved list?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, while-loop

So I have this Task:

```
public async Task ProcessNewMessages()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await _exceptionHandler.WithExceptionHandling(async () =>
        {
            List<Message> newUncompletedNewMessages = await _newUncompletedMessagesJob.Execute();
            // Do stuff
        }
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

The Execute returns a list of 10 messages and I want to add a while loop in the while true that runs the whole code again as long as the Execute returns me a full list of 10 items, that runs straight after the items are done rather than waiting 30 seconds every time.

The 30 seconds will be in place to keep checking if there are new messages and is ireelevant to the Task of handling them.

So to rephrase my question: How do I rerun code based on the list returned by Execute() having 10 messages?

Comment: You are awaiting the call, so the main thread will wait for it to be completed, no need to create your own timer. Just check if there are 10 messages and continue or not.

Comment: I think you should perhaps clarify what you want to do. I read the description twice and I'm still not sure what your actual intent is.

Comment: Mixing Task-based asynchrony with `Thread.Sleep` is a big no-no. If you *must* wait a constant amount of time (which you usually don't; prefer mechanisms that can signal their own completion), use `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the code and the question. The timer is there to run code to see if there are new messages irrelevant to the task of handling them.

Comment: `while (true)`/`Thread.Sleep` is such a bad pattern - especially so inside an `async` method.

Comment: Could you replace the `var` before the `newUncompletedNewMessages` with the actual type of the variable? Also could you include the `WithExceptionHandling` method in the question?

Comment: What should happen, if `Execute()` returns less then 10 elements? Can't you simply use `foreach (var message in await _newUncompletedMessagesJob.Execute())`? within your lambda?

Comment: @GWimpassinger if Exectute returns less than 10 elements I know it are the last messages that are to be send and after handling those it will wait 30 sec to check for messages again. Which is the behavior wanted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public async Task ProcessNewMessages()
{
    while (true)
    {
        IEnumerable<MessageToSend> uncompletedNewMessages = new List<MessageToSend>();
        do
        {
            await _exceptionHandler.WithExceptionHandling(async () =>
            {
                uncompletedNewMessages = await _newUncompletedMessagesJob.Execute();
                // DoStuff
            });
        } while (uncompletedNewMessages.Count() == 10)
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
}
```

I have an answer.

I read people not liking the Thread.Sleep, but this is a webjob running continuously to check for new messages. Now this doesn't need to run every second, because there might not be new message every second, but they can keep on coming in throughout the day. Let me know your suggestions how to do that differently.

Edit: Thanks for the explanation Jeroen

Comment: The issue is not about not "liking" the `Thread.Sleep`. If you are in an `async` method (on a `Task`) use `await Task.Delay`, not `Thread.Sleep`. `Task.Delay` allows the runtime to put the thread the task is currently using back in commission while the task is put in the fridge, waiting for a timer to expire. `Thread.Sleep` instead prevents the thread from being used for other tasks at all. If you want a thread, use a thread, not a `Task`.